# Intent in Windows Phone development in C#

Tags: c#, android, iphone, .net, windows-phone-7

I am developing cross platform application.

My Requirement is I want to launch my child app from my parent app.

In Android I achieved this by following steps in C#

1. I Created and deployed Child application .apk file to my Android mobile
2. In Parent application have place a button and on click of button I have put below code and it works and able to launch child app

   ```
           Intent i = new Intent ();
           i.SetAction (Intent.ActionMain);
           i.AddCategory (Intent.CategoryLauncher);  

           // Pakage Name and Class name of my child app
           i.SetComponent (new ComponentName ("ChildpkgName", "ChildClsName"));
           i.SetFlags (Intent.Flags);
           StartActivity (i);
   ```

Similarly, I want to achieve in Windows Phone in C#.

Currently I have Parent application and Child application put on my Windows Phone. 
I have used Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone and Windows Phone sdk7.1 for developing these Parent and Child .xap

My System OS: Windows 7.

Please help me in launching .xap file of Child app on Button click in Parent App.

This there anything similar to Android Intent in Windows Phone in C#?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to launch another application in Windows Phone 7. In Windows Phone 8, you can do that by registering a custom URI scheme: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx